# XSD Error Element element is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I wrote a XML and tried to validate it against a XSD but I get some errors and I can't resolve them.

Here are the error messages:

```
Error - Line 38, 128: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 38; columnNumber: 128; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_symptomsmedicindatapatientpatientshospital' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
    Error - Line 43, 129: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 43; columnNumber: 129; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_diagnosemedicindatapatientpatientshospital' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
    Error - Line 48, 131: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 48; columnNumber: 131; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_medicationmedicindatapatientpatientshospital' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
    Error - Line 66, 54: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 66; columnNumber: 54; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_doctorsstaffhospital' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
    Error - Line 108, 87: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 108; columnNumber: 87; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_fieldsnursesstaffhospital' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

I understand that something is wrong with the elements 'element' at the specific lines. I checked my XSD for more than a hour now but I can't see the mistakes in it.

I hope that you can help me.

**XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hospital xmlns="http://www.hospitalinfo.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hospitalinfo.com hospital.xsd">
   <patients>
      <patient id="1954A">
         <basicdata>
            <address>
               <firstname title="Dr.">Nina</firstname>
               <lastname>Meyer</lastname>
               <street housenumber="22/3a">Münchnerstraße</street>
               <postcode>65908</postcode>
               <location>Grasensteinen</location>
            </address>
         </basicdata>
         <medicindata>
            <symptoms>
               <symptom>pain in chest</symptom>
               <symptom>breathlessness</symptom>
               <symptom>emesis</symptom>
            </symptoms>
            <diagnose>
               <disorder>myocardial infarktion</disorder>
               <disorder>angina pectoris</disorder>
            </diagnose>
            <medication>
               <medicament>Betablocker</medicament>
               <medicament>Azetylsalizylsäure</medicament>
            </medication>
         </medicindata>
      </patient>
      <patient id="4969Z">
         <basicdata>
            <address>
               <firstname title="">Chris</firstname>
               <lastname>Richard</lastname>
               <street housenumber="3">Wielandsraße</street>
               <postcode>98150</postcode>
               <location>Blumensee</location>
            </address>
         </basicdata>
         <medicindata>
            <symptoms>
               <symptom>abdominal pain</symptom>
            </symptoms>
            <diagnose>
               <disorder>acute appendictis</disorder>
            </diagnose>
         </medicindata>
      </patient>
   </patients>
   <staff>
      <doctors>
         <doctor>
            <name>
               <firstname title="Dr.">Leyla</firstname>
               <lastname>Richardson</lastname>
            </name>
            <fields>
               <field>cardiology</field>
            </fields>
         </doctor>
         <doctor>
            <name>
               <firstname title="">Lara</firstname>
               <lastname>Nick</lastname>
            </name>
            <fields>
               <field>general practitioner</field>
            </fields>
         </doctor>
      </doctors>
      <nurses>
         <nurse>
            <name>
               <firstname title="">Mell</firstname>
               <lastname>Grey</lastname>
            </name>
            <fields>
               <field>cardiology</field>
            </fields>
         </nurse>
      </nurses>
   </staff>
</hospital>
```

**XSD:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.hospitalinfo.com" targetNamespace="http://www.hospitalinfo.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:element name="hospital">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="patients" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="patient">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name="basicdata">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                       <xs:element name="address">
                                          <xs:complexType>
                                             <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="firstname">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                      <xs:attribute name="housenumber" type="xs:string" />
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                                <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
                                                <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
                                                <xs:element name="postcode" type="xs:string" />
                                                <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string" />
                                             </xs:sequence>
                                          </xs:complexType>
                                       </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                              </xs:element>
                              <xs:element name="medicindata">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                       <xs:element name="symptoms">
                                          <xs:complexType>
                                             <xs:element name="symptom" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                          </xs:complexType>
                                       </xs:element>
                                       <xs:element name="diagnose">
                                          <xs:complexType>
                                             <xs:element name="disorder" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                          </xs:complexType>
                                       </xs:element>
                                       <xs:element name="medication">
                                          <xs:complexType>
                                             <xs:element name="medicament" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                          </xs:complexType>
                                       </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                              </xs:element>
                           </xs:sequence>
                           <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="staff">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="doctors">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:element name="doctor">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                 <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="name">
                                       <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="firstname">
                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                   <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />
                                                </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
                                          </xs:sequence>
                                       </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="fields">
                                       <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:element name="field" type="xs:string" />
                                       </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                 </xs:sequence>
                              </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                     <xs:element name="nurses">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                 <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="name">
                                       <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="firstname">
                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                   <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />
                                                </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
                                          </xs:sequence>
                                       </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="fields">
                                       <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:element name="field" type="xs:string" />
                                       </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                 </xs:sequence>
                              </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is complaining about your schema.

You have `xs:element` as a direct child of the `xs:complexType` element in several places, which is not allowed.

You need to have those elements nested in a compositor, such as `xs:sequence`, `xs:choice`, or `xs:all`.

For instance, to correct the issue with the symptom, you could use `xs:choice`:

```
<xs:element name="symptoms">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="symptom" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Read this quick tutorial that explain the distinction between them and why you might use one over the other: http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/01/xml-schema-xsd-using-compositors/